# How do I suppress or filter Tkinter error messages with python?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm running Python-2.7 on a Mac (OSX 10.11.3) via Anaconda (conda v4.0.5), and I keep seeing this error pop up when I create Tkinter (v8.5.18) windows:

> 2016-04-18 11:32:08.417 python[43501:3308828] setCanCycle: is deprecated. Please use setCollectionBehavior instead

A (very simple) example of code that produces this error is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import Tkinter as Tk

master=Tk.Tk()
master.mainloop()
```

I know this is a well-known issue with my particular software/OS combo, but all I really need is a method to suppress this specific error message from within my python script. For example, if I could make a filter for the phrase "setCanCycle: is deprecated" and send any errors or warnings containing that string to /dev/null, I would be very happy indeed!